# Trying to make a slide in out animation of my codes that I have done in CSS but failed

Tags: html, css, hover, css-animations, mouseover

I am trying to do an animation where the user drags the cursor on the button, it slide out and when the user drag out of the button, it slide in. I have made another code on another link below, is able to but trying to do it on my full codes by me on the link "Fully by me:" when I trying on my wrapper id, it does not work. May I Know what should I do to make it slide out and in when user mouse over? Thanks.

Fully by me:https://jsfiddle.net/bftjvsex/73/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="main-item menu">
    <span class="line line01"></span>
    <span class="line line02"></span>
    <span class="line line03"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
  /*border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;*/
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #648B79;
  display: inline-block;
  /*border-radius:500px;*/
  /*margin:10px;*/
  /*margin-left: 5px;*/
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.box { margin-top:-48px;}
.box{
  background: #648B79;
   width: 35px;
  height: 35px; 
  display: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
   position: relative; z-index:1;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper {
    background: #29afd1;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.main-item {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
}

.line01 {
  top: 9%;
}

.line02 {
  top: 39%;
}

.line03 {
  top: 69%;
}

.menu.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
}

.menu.close .line02,
.menu.close .line03 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
}

.main:hover .box {
    margin-right: 0;
  display:block;
    transform-origin: top;
    /*
    animation-name: balance;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 110ms;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    */
    animation: balance 1.5s ease-in-out 110ms 1 alternate;
}

@keyframes balance { 
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {right: 48px;}
}

.fa-facebook-square {
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 6%;
  padding: 11px;
  background: #648B79;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

i.fa-github:hover,
i.fa-facebook-square:hover {
  color: white;
  padding: 11px;
  width: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.fa-github {
  margin-top: 290px;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 11px;
  width: 6%;
  background: #648B79;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Edit by me: https://jsfiddle.net/9dwk8vzg/84/

Comment: Anybody have the correct answer for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position` to your `.main` div

```
.main {
  position: relative;
}
```

and some default `left position` to your `.box` div

```
.box {
  left:150px; 
}
```

```js
$("#wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".menu").toggleClass("close");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#wrapper {
  /*border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;*/
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #648B79;
  display: inline-block;
  /*border-radius:500px;*/
  /*margin:10px;*/
  /*margin-left: 5px;*/
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10000;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
}
.box { margin-top:-48px;}
.box{
  background: #648B79;
   width: 35px;
  height: 35px; 
  left:150px; 
  display: none;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
   position: relative; z-index:1;
   transition: all 250ms ease;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #wrapper {
    background: #29afd1;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 250px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.main-item {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
}

.line01 {
  top: 9%;
}

.line02 {
  top: 39%;
}

.line03 {
  top: 69%;
}

.menu.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
}

.menu.close .line02,
.menu.close .line03 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
}

.main:hover .box {
 margin-right: 0;
  display:block;
 transform-origin: top;
 /*
 animation-name: balance;
 animation-duration: 1.5s;
 animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 animation-delay: 110ms;
 animation-iteration-count: 1;
 animation-direction: alternate;
 */
 animation: balance 1.5s ease-in-out 110ms 1 alternate;
}

@keyframes balance { 
 from {left: 0px;}
    to {right: 48px;}
}

.fa-facebook-square {
  margin-top: 250px;
  font-size: 70px;
  width: 6%;
  padding: 11px;
  background: #648B79;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

i.fa-github:hover,
i.fa-facebook-square:hover {
  color: white;
  padding: 11px;
  width: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-delay: 1s;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.fa-github {
  margin-top: 290px;
  font-size: 36px;
  padding: 11px;
  width: 6%;
  background: #648B79;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a id="toggle-btn" href="#" class="menu-btn">
  <div class="main">

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="main-item menu">
        <span class="line line01"></span>
        <span class="line line02"></span>
        <span class="line line03"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     
    </div>
    
 </div>
</a>

  

<i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="font-size:30px"></i>
<i class="fa fa-github" style="font-size:30px"></i>
```

Comment: Hi I am so sorry, that not what I really wants, could you refer to the question. If there any problem understanding my question, drop down in the comments below. Thanks

Comment: you want  `.box` div to be slide in and out on hover over `#wrapper` div right or anything else??